# DotnetNuke 2scx suppressing Font-Awesome class

Tags: font-awesome, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

#1
Add an HTML module to a page, then add the following tag via html source:

```
<em class="icon-featured fas fa-user"></em>
```

Nothing happens.  Go back to source, and see that the editor has automatically commented out the tag.
Removing the FAS and FA-USER classes cause it to show up without issue, so it has to be something with font-awesome.

#2
There are actually two things that happen...
if the html component is already on the page and you add the FA icons, THEN add the 2sxc module, it squishes them.
If the 2sxc module is on the page first, it comments them out.

#3
This...

```
<p>before -<em class="icon-featured fas fa-user"></em>-after
</p>
```

becomes..

```
<p>before <em class="icon-featured fas fa-user"></em> --> -after</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding #1:  This probably has to do with the configuration of the HTML Editor Provider.  The CK Editor has a freature that will clean up HTML.

Here is how to fix it: https://dnncommunity.org/blogs/Post/2841/Help-DNN-CKEditor-is-cleaning-my-HTML